# ORA-00257 even when Oracle is in NOARCHIVELOG mode

Tags: oracle-11g

One of my jUnit tests fails with the following exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00257: archiver error. Connect internal only, until freed.

The Oracle error code refers to (for lack of better words/knowledge) `ARCHIVELOG` mode related issue. But, I made sure that the DB is running in `NOARCHIVELOG` mode. I checked `V$DATABAS`E table and made sure that `log_archive_start=false`.

Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: it can also refer to a lack of space in your redo-tablespace which something else than the archivelogs AFAIK...

Comment: Is it possible to move this question to ServerFault? I don't want people to close this question as irrelevant, and lose sight of it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the archiver cannot write or has no space in the destination specified by log_archive_dest. Check the results of "archive log list"